# Ajax does not work in this case and I don't know why

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm trying to receive some data as json from a php file, the php seems to be good and the html too, but te jquery file doesn't do the .done function and I can't find why.
The Jquery version that I use is 3.1.0, and I'm using bootstrap for styles but I think it isn't important.

The HTML file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Registro Chat</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>
<body>
<h1>Chat 2.0</h1>
<div class="container col-md- mt-4">
    <form id="formulario">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="usuario">Nombre de Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="usuario" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduzca el nombre de usuario">
        <p id="p-usuario"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="email">Email</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduzca su email">
        <p id="p-email"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contra1">Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contra1" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Introduzca una contraseña">
        <p id="p-contra1"></p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contra2">Repita la Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" id="contra2" placeholder="Repita su contraseña">
        <p id="p-contra2"></p>
      </div>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success bg-success">Enviar</button>
      <a href="principal.html"><button type="button" class="btn btn-success bg-success">Inicio de Sesión</button></a>
    </form>
</div>  
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script src="accionregistro.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

The JQuery file:

```
$(document).ready(principal);

function principal(){

$('#formulario').submit(runAjax);
}

function runAjax(event){

var enviados = {
    'usuario' : $('#usuario').val(),
    'email' : $('#email').val(),
    'contra1' : $('#contra1').val(),
    'contra2' : $('#contra2').val()
    };

$.ajax({
    type        : 'POST',
    url         : 'backendregistro.php',
    data        : enviados,
    dataType    : 'json',
    encode      : true  
})
.done(function(datos){
    alert();

    if(datos.exito){
            alert();
            $('0#p-usuario').text(datos.mensaje);
    }else{
        if(datos.error.vacio){
                alert(datos.error.vacio);
                //$('#p-usuario').text(datos.error.vacio);
        }
        if(datos.error.usuario){
                $('#p-usuario').text(datos.error.usuario);
        }
        if(datos.error.email){
                $('#p-email').text(datos.error.email);
        }
        if(datos.error.notmatch){
                $('#p-contraseña1').text(datos.error.notmatch);
        }
        }

});
event.preventDefault();
}
```

PHP file:

```php
<?php  
$error=array();
$datos=array();

if(empty($_POST['usuario'])||empty($_POST['contra1'])||empty($_POST['contra2'])||empty($_POST['email'])){
    $error['vacio']="No puede haber campos en blanco";
}else{
    echo
        $usuario = $_POST['usuario'].
        $email = $_POST['email'].
        $contraseña1 = $_POST['contra1'].
        $contraseña2 = $_POST['contra2'];
}
//definimos la conexion a la base de datos
$mysqli = new mysqli('localhost','chat','chat2019','chat');

//comprobamos si el email ya existe
$mysqli -> query("select * from users where email='".$email."'");
if($mysqli->affected_rows!=0&&!empty($email)){
    $error['email']="Ese email ya está registrado";
} 
//comprobamos que no exista el usuario
$mysqli->query("select * from users where user='".$usuario."'");
if($mysqli->affected_rows!=0 && !empty($usuario)){
    $error['usuario']="Ya existe ese nombre de usuario";
}

//si no hay errores hacemos el insert
if(empty($error)){
    $datos['exito']=true;
    $datos['mensaje']="Usuario registrado correctamente";
    $mysqli->query("insert into users values ('".$usuario."','".$contraseña1."','".$email."')");
}else{
    $datos['exito']=false;
    $datos['error']=$error;
}

echo json_encode($datos);  

?>
```

When I try to see in the console if every thing is going well, it seems that the json is being sent but then the done function doesn't work. I'm soo noob at web programing, I know that probably the way I'm doing is very unsecure, but I only want to know why it doesn't works, thanks you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem, missing white spaces before and after the function affected_rows in the php file. Thanks for the answers.

Comment: `affected_rows` is for DDL queries like `INSERT`, `UPDATE`, or `DELETE`. You should be using `num_rows` to get the number of rows returned by a `SELECT` query.

Comment: Even better: If you're not actually using the data returned by the `SELECT` queries, use `SELECT COUNT(*)`, fetch the result, and get the number of rows from that.

Comment: White space shouldn't matter after `$mysqli->affected_rows`.

Answer (score -1):

First of all as per [jQuery doc](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), `done` callback is similar to `success`. So you have to try adding `fail()` and `always()` callbacks in order to determine response.

Comment: yes I've tryed but the function fail() doesnt shown nothing